Preserving std::forward_range during chunk transformation?
encode below is a dumbed down version of a transformation I am working on (run it on godbolt):
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>

int main() {
    static constexpr auto arr = std::array{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    static constexpr auto encode = std::views::chunk(3) |
                                   std::views::transform([](auto chunk) {
                                       std::array<int, 4> a{};
                                       auto i = 0;
                                       for (const auto j : chunk) {
                                           a.at(i++) = j;
                                       }
                                       a.at(3) = a.at(0);
                                       return a;
                                   }) |
                                   std::views::join;
    auto encoded = arr | encode;

    static_assert(std::ranges::contiguous_range<decltype(arr)>);
    static_assert(std::ranges::input_range<decltype(encoded)>);
    static_assert(not std::ranges::forward_range<decltype(encoded)>);

    for (const auto i : encoded) {
        std::cout << i;
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}

Output:
123145647007

As the static_asserts show, although the input is a contiguous_range, the output is not even a forward_range. It is not necessarily a problem for me, but as a matter of principle, I would like my adaptors to be as range property-preserving as possible. Is there an obvious way to rewrite encode to make it preserve forward_ranges or is that type of chunk transformation always going to break that property?

Edit, additional question:
If there is no obvious way, is there a non-obvious way, like one that would involve implementing the range adaptor from scratch?

As it turns out, the answer is yes, there is a way to rewrite encode to even preserve random_access_ranges and sized_ranges (run it on godbolt):
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>

struct encode_fn : std::ranges::range_adaptor_closure<encode_fn> {
    template <std::ranges::viewable_range R>
        requires std::convertible_to<std::ranges::range_reference_t<R>, int>
    constexpr auto operator()(R &&r) const {
        return std::views::cartesian_product(
                   std::forward<R>(r) | std::views::chunk(3),
                   std::views::iota(0, 4)) |
               std::views::transform([](auto indexed) -> int {
                   auto [v, i] = indexed;
                   if (i == 3) {
                       return v[0];
                   }
                   if (i > std::ranges::size(v) - 1) {
                       return 0;
                   }
                   return v[i];
               });
    }
};

int main() {
    static constexpr auto arr = std::array{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

    static constexpr encode_fn encode{};
    auto encoded = arr | encode;

    static_assert(std::ranges::contiguous_range<decltype(arr)>);
    static_assert(std::ranges::random_access_range<decltype(encoded)>);
    static_assert(std::ranges::sized_range<decltype(encoded)>);
    static_assert(std::ranges::size(arr | encode) == 12);

    for (const auto i : encoded) {
        std::cout << i;
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}

Same output. With the help of cartesian_product, we handle every chunk multiple times, producing one transformed chunk item at a time, thus removing the need to ever store intermediate chunks.

The problem isn't chunk, the problem is the transform | join.
Let me annotate the types. We have:

array (contiguous range of int const&)
... | chunk (random access range of contiguous range of int const&)
... | transform (random access range of prvalue array<int, 4>)
... | join (input range of int&)

The problem is, when you are joining a range of prvalue ranges, each next range has to be stored somewhere while you're iterating over it. The range has to be somewhere for your iterators to refer to it. And the only place for it to meaningfully exist is... inside of the join_view. That's why the specification has this member:
// exposition only, present only if is_reference_v<InnerRng> is false
non-propagating-cache<remove_cv_t<InnerRng>> inner_;    

And once your range has to do stashing, it can't be anything stronger than input, because you can't have two independent iterators into it (because those iterators would share that stash and can't independently mutate it).

Thanks. Very clear explanation as usual. It seems you made me realize that I had a solution in my recent musings, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/79079550/3246135. Maybe it wouldn't even be inefficient? Any opinion on that?

Although this answer gives a perfect explanation about why the OP solution does not preserve forward ranges, it does not technically answer the question. It could give an impression that there is no way to rewrite the adaptor to preserve forward ranges, when in fact, there is (see accepted answer).
